# Working on a 64-bit MVC3 application, Razor views cannot load models due to incorrect format

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am coding a 64-bit MVC3 application, and all my views are showing an errors when I am editing them. The reason is VS2010 could not load the view models due a bad image format.

I suppose this is due to VS2010 being a 32-bit application. Is there anyway round the problem>

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718178/mvc3-project-will-not-load-dll-properly-aftering-moving-to-win7-64-bit-machine

Comment: Ok, just edited the question. The errors are showing in Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that Visual Studio is using the 32-bit MSBuild to compile the Razor views in realtime.  I've tried to override it to use 64-bit MSBuild with no luck.